# Is there any built in lambda for is notNone in python

Tags: python, oop, typing

I see the following idiom repeated several times in python  `X = filter(lambda x: x is not None, X))`

I was hoping there is a builtin function for `is not None`(in its standard library or something similar to apache-commons for java) in python.

In my code I have organized it as

```
def isNotNone(X: Any) -> bool:
    return True if X is not None else False

X = filter(isNotNone, X)
```

Comment: `filter(None,X)` does almost the same. It filters out `None`, but also 0 and empty strings, "falsy' objects...

Comment: `return True if X is not None else False` => `return X is not None` (more pythonic!)

Comment: I would use `X = (elt for elt in X if elt is not None)` instead :)

Comment: good point. Using `filter` or `map` with a `lambda` is slow and complex. But OP is looking for a builtin. `bool` is the closest thing (but filters out other elements)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `None.__ne__`, i.e. the not-equal check of `None`:

```
>>> lst = [0, [], None, ""]
>>> list(filter(None.__ne__, lst))
[0, [], '']
```

Technically, this does not test `x is not None` but `x != None`, which *could* yield a different result for some cases, e.g. for classes that compare equal to `None`, but for most practical cases, it should probably work.

---

As noted in comments, this does not behave the same -- or is not even defined -- for all versions of Python, some properly returning `True` or `False` and others yielding `NotImplemented` for most values, which coincidentally "works", too, but should not be relied on. Instead, it's probably a better idea just to define your own `def` or `lambda` or (for this use case) use a list comprehension.

Comment: Interestingly `None.__ne__` doesn't return `True` for most non-None objects, it returns `NotImplemented`. Fortunately this evaluates to true.

Comment: `list(map(None.__ne__, [0, [], None, ""])) == [NotImplemented, NotImplemented, False, NotImplemented]` on my machine, Python 3.6.3.

Comment: @AlexHall `[True, True, False, True]` on mine, using somewhat dated Python 3.4.2 (and on 2.7.9, `None.__ne__` does not seem to exist...)

Comment: Actually `None.__ne__` will always do the right thing, because even if the other class implemented something special for `x != None`, that only gets invoked when using the `!=` operator, not calling `None.__ne__(x)`.

Comment: This is a bad idea, because it very subtly relies on the behavior of NotImplemented (in a way you didn't even realize when writing it), and because it encourages using `None.__eq__` to test whether things are None, and [that doesn't work at all](https://ideone.com/rlz3qd).

Comment: @user2357112 About the `NotImplemented`: As I said, I tested this on a version of Python 3 that does not do that but returns `True` and `False` instead (for the shown elements at least). But anyway, I am aware of and agree that this solution has it's flaws.

Comment: Unfortunately, this [is not really recommended](https://bugs.python.org/issue35712#msg380603) and in the newer Python versions, it issues a warning. You should use list comprehensions instead.

Comment: It doesn't work in Python 3.12 anymore.